# How to solve this triangle problem in Visual Basic? I don't know if I'm doing it right

Tags: vba, loops, input, basic, triangle

> Make a program that reads a positive integer no greater than 10, and prints a triangle of numbers as follows:
> If the number read were 5, then it should print:
>
> 1
>
> 22
>
> 333
>
> 4444
>
> 55555
>
> The program must reread another number until the number entered is greater than 10.

I have tried [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yttSI.png), but I don't know if it is correct:

```
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    num = InputBox(" enter a number")
    For i = 1 To num Step 1
        If i = 1 Then

            ListBox1.Items.Add(1)

        ElseIf i = 2 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(22)

        ElseIf i = 3 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(333)
        ElseIf i = 4 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(4444)
        ElseIf i = 5 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(55555)
        ElseIf i = 6 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(666666)

        ElseIf i = 7 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(7777777)
        ElseIf i = 8 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(88888888)
        ElseIf i = 9 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(999999999)
        ElseIf i = 10 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(1010101010101010101010)

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: `For i = 1 To num: ListBox1.Items.Add String(i, CStr(i)): Next i`

Comment: It happens every year, like clockwork :)

Comment: "dont know if this is correct" -- why not run it and find out?